# FCM is not working in Vivo after application killed

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM is working fine with all devices when app is killed except vivo, oppo.
I have tried enable auto start in settings for app but, still not working.
we are stuck in this issue from longer time.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!!

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    AppLog.e(TAG, "Firebase From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage == null) return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        AppLog.e(TAG, "Firebase Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        AppLog.e(TAG, "Firebase Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        handleDataMessage(remoteMessage.getData());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

FCM will not work in the killed state for some of the custom ROMs.
For e.g. Vivo, Oppo, Mi etc.
The thing is these ROMs block the notifications by default for apps except for some white-labeled apps like Fb, Whatsapp. Most of these apps come bundled with the ROMs. Some of them have their own push notification service.

To make it work on these ROMs, try the below suggestions:

> Use notification payload instead of the data payload.  You can try to send a test notification from the FCM test page to the Vivo/Oppo device and check if it works for you before trying to implement it.

If you still want to use data payload:

1. Check if the notification payload has priority as a High priority.
2. Check if the notification is enabled for your app in the device
3. Enable autostart for your app from security settings
4. Disable battery optimization for your app from the app list page in the settings.